# Utilizing 2 Layouts within a ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, bitmap

I have been trying to implement a ListView that utilizes 2 seperate Layouts depending on the row. The first layout has 1 imageview, and the second layout has 2 imageviews.

I would like to make it so that I can get each row within the ListView to contain alternating layouts, but also be able to use up what is in the ArrayList bitmapArray;

So for example, the first row would contain the first 2 bitmap images, and the second row would contain 1 large bitmap image, the 3rd row would be 2 more bitmap images side by side... and so forth.

**UPDATE**

**I have got it working somewhat, and issue remains where the images are not being seperated properly. It is just reusing a total of 4 different pictures and is seperating them oddly... I will try to illustrate below**

Each number represents a picture in the BitmapArray (there are 20 images total 0 - 19)

NEEDS TO BE

```
[   0   ]
[ 1 , 2 ]
[   3   ]
[ 4,  5 ]
[   6   ]
[ 7,  8 ]
[   9   ]
[10 , 11]
[  12   ]
[13,  14]
[  15   ]
[16,  17]
[  18   ]
[ 19, --]
```

UPDATED PATTERN FOR DER GOLEM

```
[   0   ]
[ 1 , 2 ]
[   2   ]
[ 3 , 4 ]
REPEAT
```

**There is only ever a total of 20 images stored in the BitmapArray. Another issue I am finding is that when I press OnItemClick on a later row (say 10) it will take me to another activity where the bitmap is enlarged ( as designed ).. the weird thing is that it will be a totally different image, one that probably corresponds with that position in the array. **

```
Here is the code that I have been working with.

    public class FeedAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Bitmap> {

        private static final int TYPE_BIG_ITEM = 0;
        private static final int TYPE_SMALL_ITEM = 1;

        public FeedAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArray) {
            super(context, R.layout.feed_listview_big);
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            ImageView ivPictureSmallOne;
            ImageView ivPictureSmallTwo;
            ImageView ivPictureBig;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return position % 2;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            Bitmap bmp = getItem(position);
            ViewHolder viewHolder;


            if (convertView == null) {
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                if (getItemViewType(position) == 0) {
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_listview_small,
                            null);
                    viewHolder.ivPictureSmallOne = (ImageView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.ivSmall1);
                    viewHolder.ivPictureSmallTwo = (ImageView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.ivSmall2);
                    viewHolder.ivPictureSmallOne.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                    viewHolder.ivPictureSmallTwo.setImageBitmap(getItem(position + 1));
                } else {
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_listview_big,
                            null);
                    viewHolder.ivPictureBig = (ImageView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.ivBig);
                    viewHolder.ivPictureBig.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                }
            }
            // Return the completed view to render on screen
            return convertView;

        }
    }
```

Comment: whats is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I just updated the question. The problem I am facing is in regards to seperating the bitmaps that are being used to populate each row. The rows alternate between 2 seperate layouts.

Comment: try looking at recycle view

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this

```
if (convertView == null) {
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    if (getItemViewType(position) == 0) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_listview_small,
                null);
        viewHolder.ivPictureSmallOne = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ivSmall1);
        viewHolder.ivPictureSmallTwo = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ivSmall2);
        viewHolder.ivPictureSmallOne.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        viewHolder.ivPictureSmallTwo.setImageBitmap(getItem(position + 1));
    } else {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_listview_big,
                null);
        viewHolder.ivPictureBig = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ivBig);
        viewHolder.ivPictureBig.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
}
// Return the completed view to render on screen
return convertView;
```

to

```
if (convertView == null)
{
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    // Every 3rd image, load the "big" one
    if ((getItemViewType(position) % 3) == 0)
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_listview_big,
                null);
        viewHolder.ivPictureBig = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ivBig);
        viewHolder.ivPictureBig.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
    // If not dividable by 3, load the 2 "small" ones
    else
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_listview_small,
                null);
        viewHolder.ivPictureSmallOne = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ivSmall1);
        viewHolder.ivPictureSmallTwo = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ivSmall2);
        viewHolder.ivPictureSmallOne.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        viewHolder.ivPictureSmallTwo.setImageBitmap(getItem(position + 1));
    }
}
// Return the completed view to render on screen
return convertView;
```

Comment: would I keep the existing getItemViewType? and getViewTypeCount?

Comment: I updated the project details to reflect what it is that I am seeing in result to your changes. It seems odd, but I am going to keep working on it. Let me know if you think of something else.

Comment: Very strange... only every 3rd row it should appear big, the other 2 should appear small and close to each other. Let me see what I did overlook. It seems that this `if ((getItemViewType(position) % 3) == 0)` is acting weird. I'd try this instead: `if (((position + 1) % 3) == 0)`.

Comment: The reason being that the position index is "off by one": position = 0, 1, 2 (third!), ... So, (position + 1) = 1, 2, 3 (third! position is still 2, but we check the "plus one" version), ... And this would make the modulo operation check the right item.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your get view.

```
 position = MakeNewPosition(position);
```

the make new position method will give you the new corrected postion.

```
 private int MakeNewPosition(int position)
    {
        return position+(position/2);
    }
```

hope this works. try out

Comment: Not quite. It results in some really strange behavior. Thanks though.